# Finding common clusters across multiple data sets

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have several kmeans() results (T1, T2..., T8) and want to find which clusters are common across all of them.

I am having difficulties with this as the clusters are labelled arbitrarily starting from 1, so comparing based on these labels is pointless.

I had an idea to combine the raw data for T1, T2... into one dataset and perform kmeans() on that, however I am wary of this as it will affect things like the optimal k value, and furthermore I do not know how I could differentiate between the raw T1, T2... datasets once they have been merged and kmeans() performed.

Comment: This is a CV question, not a SO question. But I would 1. make sure that the variables used for the kmeans are exactly the same, and treated in the same way across the datasets, and 2. Observe the differences in the centroids of each of the cluster solutions across the datasets.